# Twitter list timeline API?

Tags: php, api, twitter

Greetings,

It appears that the default Twitter List API categorizes tweets within each user. Example:
http://api.twitter.com/1/lists/members.json?slug=cnnnews&owner_screen_name=cnn

I was wondering if there's an API to get the timeline for a twitter list, or if implementing this requires a series of workarounds??

Comment: Check this link [Improving the JSON/P Twitter Widget](http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/2010/01/15/improving-the-jsonp-twitter-widget/) and this one as well [How to add Tweets to your blog and debugging basic JavaScript: Why did Twitter.com/JavaScript/Blogger JSONP Widget stop working?](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAddTweetsToYourBlogAndDebuggingBasicJavaScriptWhyDidTwittercomJavaScriptBloggerJSONPWidgetStopWorking.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a REST API for getting a twitter list timeline. You can find documentation for it here: [Twitter REST API Method: GET list statuses](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554716/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-GET-list-statuses). I hope this is what you are looking for. Good luck!